# Brachistochrones on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

Let $(M,g,V)$ be a Riemannian manifold with potential $V\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$. Let $\gamma : I\to M$ be a smooth curve, $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an open interval. We say that $\gamma$ is the trajectory of a constrained unit-mass point-particle (or, simply, a *constrained trajectory*) if

$\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}=\langle X, \nu \rangle \cdot \nu $

for every $t\in I$, where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection, $X:=\mathrm{grad}_gV$ is the "force of gravity" and $\nu:=\dot{\gamma}/||\dot{\gamma}||$ is the tangent direction (whenever $\dot{\gamma}\neq 0$). I think this definition reduces to the "standard" one when $M$ is flat $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $V=-x_3$ (if it doesn't, please correct it so that it fits the physical viewpoint).

Let's say a constrained trajectory $\gamma$ is a *brachistochrone* between points $a, b\in M$, with $V(a)>V(b)$, if

1) $\gamma (0)=a$, $\dot{\gamma}(0)=0$, there is $T>0$ with $\gamma(T)=b$, and

2) for every other constrained trajectory $\eta$, with $\eta(0)=a$ and $\dot{\eta}(0)=0$ with $\eta(T^{*})=b$ for $T^{*}>0$, we have $T\leq T^{*}$.

---

> Has this concept already been studied? Does it have any interesting applications?

---

> Can anything interesting be said if $M$ is, say, the round $2$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $V$ is $-x_3$? Or what in the case $M$ is homogeneus (such as the hyperbolic plane) ?

---

*Note:* this question was just out of curiosity, I'm not doing research on this.

Comment: Do you really mean covariantly costant in the last sentence of your question?  The hyperbolic plane has no covariantly constant vector fields.  Indeed, the existence of a covariantly constant vector field implies that the universal cover has a flat factor.

Comment: Thank you. I was just thinking of a vector field that resembled, in the hyperbolic context, the classic case in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So maybe this just makes no sense. Edited.

Comment: Could you please check your equation for the CONSTRAINED TRAJECTORY. For me it implies that the acceleration  is proportional to the velocity which means  that the trajectories are reparameterized geodesics of the metric $g$ (the choice of the function $V$ affects the "time" on the trajectory   but not the  trajectory considered as an unparameterized curve).  

Comment: @VSM: perhaps I indeed don't remember well how physics works! I just thought that the force by the constraint would compensate the force the body exerts on it, which I thought is the normal component of grav. force, so the resulting force would be the tang. component of grav. force. And then write " F=ma ". Feel absolutely free to edit according to the right physical equation. [I will have a look to the thing in a later moment]  

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think the equation of motion should be $\nabla_\dot{\gamma} \dot{\gamma}=X$.

Comment: @TR: I'm not sure it works: in the case $(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathrm{flat},-x_3)$ isn't your eqn. that of a *free* particle under the gravitational potential? (so, solutions with $0$ initial velocity would have to be vertical lines?)

Comment: Uhm... I'm starting to think my setting is ill-defined...  Any suggestions?

Comment: I wrote the equation of motion in fact, not the equation of the brachistochrone. However, it is "constrained" in the sense that if connection and gradient are understood with respect to the inner metric on $S^2$, it is a purely intrinsic ODE. 

I don't understand how you got your equation, is it the Euler-Lagrange equation of the time functional ? I don't remember if the derivation of the brachistochrone equation in the euclidean case rely uses the "flatness" to be able to write the equation in a nice form.

Comment: Well, by "constrained" I don't mean "constrained within the manifold $M$" (which makes no sense, if you think of $M$ as an abstract manifold), but rather "constrained within a fixed rail/track inside (i.e. 1-dimentional submanifold of) $M$". Since once you put the particle on the rail initially at rest its motion is uniquely determined (by the potential, and by the force exerted by the constraint - which is orthogonal to $\gamma(I)$), I thought [continued]

Comment: [continued] we could identify the track $\gamma(I)$ with the trajectory $\gamma : I\to M$ itself. Among the various $\gamma$ joining two (suitable) fixed points $a,b$, there will be one that minimizes the time needed by the particle to reach the endpoint $b$ ...